# Where are the remaining points on the tensorboard embedding projector, which are not down sampled from tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow, visualization, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard

I have seen "For faster results, the data will be sampled down to 10,000 points." in the t-SNE embedding projector.  What does the tensorboard do with the remaining data points? (if there are 25,000 points and where do 15,000 points go?) It will just not render those points or render them on the original point e.g., (0, 0, 0) in a 3-dimension plot?

Where do we config the number of rendering points?

Comment: probably more importantly, HOW does TB select the 10,000 points? does it simply take the first 10K points OR, random sample of size 10K? something else?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/993f69c3d6a90854e4fd0be039d3f4e14e5de422/tensorboard/plugins/projector/vz_projector/data.ts)

```
let sampledIndices = this.shuffledDataIndices.slice(0, TSNE_SAMPLE_SIZE);
```

TSNE_SAMPLE_SIZE is set to 10,000 at the top of that module. Looks like the points are "shuffled" and the first 10,000 are taken. I have to wonder why it was done this way. Your way around it would be to take a sample of 10,000 or less yourself, however you want. That way Tensorboard will show all your points without shuffling or downsampling.